# Spring Boot MongoDB connection bean

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data

I have situation like this.

I'm using Spring boot 1.3.2, and I have installed MongoDB on my pc
I have added dependency

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb
```

And when I run my web application, database connection automatically start working.

I didn't configure a thing.

Now I want to connect spring security like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
                                                   throws Exception {
  auth
    .jdbcAuthentication()
      .dataSource(dataSource);
}
```

My question is what is default bean name for Spring Boot DataSource and can I override it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're planning to use `Mongodb` as your user details storage, i.e. *username*, *password*, etc. , then you **can't** use the `jdbcAuthentication()`. Instead, You could use a `UserDetailsService` in order to achieve the same:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired private MongoTemplate template;

    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService((String username) -> {
                    User user = template.findOne(Query.query(Criteria.where("username").is(username)), User.class, "users");

                    if (user == null) throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid User");

                    return new UserDetails(...);
                });
    }
}
```

In the prceeding sample, i supposed that you have a `users` collection with a `username` field. If exactly one user exists for the given *username*, you should return an implementation of [`UserDetails`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) corresponding to that user. Otherwise, you should throw a `UsernameNotFoundException`.

You also have other options for handling user authentication but `jdbcAuthentication()` is off the table, since you're using a `NoSQL` datastore for storing user details and `JDBC` is an abstraction for handling all the talkings with *Relational* databases.